# How to created a stacked histogram from a dataframe for two related columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have a data frame that looks like this -

```
License_type | User
A1           |  U1
A2           |  U1
A2           |  U1
A2           |  U1
A3           |  U1
A4           |  U1
A1           |  U2
A2           |  U2
A2           |  U2
A2           |  U2
A2           |  U3
A4           |  U3
```

I want to create a stacked histogram where for each User, the licenses types are stacked...

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas' `crosstab` to create the counts, then `plot.bar`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['License_type']).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use seaborn for my data visualisation.
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot

```
import seaborn as sn

sn.histplot(
    data = df,
    x = 'user',
    hue = 'License_type')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the counts using `groupby`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "License_type": ["A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A4"],
        "User": [ "U1", "U1", "U1", "U1", "U1", "U1", "U2", "U2", "U2", "U2", "U3", "U3"],
    }
)

df_counts = df.groupby(["User", "License_type"]).size()
```

So you have:

```py
>>> df_counts
User  License_type
U1    A1              1
      A2              3
      A3              1
      A4              1
U2    A1              1
      A2              3
U3    A2              1
      A4              1
dtype: int64
```

and plot as follows:

```py
df_counts.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image: bar plot]